# How to define two keys in Hibernate table?

Tags: scala, hibernate

I have the following Hibernate table declared in Scala. It has two keys (i.e. **not** a single composite key with two columns). I use`@Id` annotation to identify each key, but that seems to be the annotation to use when there's one key with multiple attributes. How to tell Hibernate that there are two independent keys?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dates")
class Dates {

    @Id
    var sk: Int = _

    @Id
    var theDate: LocalDate = _

    @Column(name = "is_holiday")
    var isHoliday: Int = _

    var year: Int = _

    var month: Int = _

    var day: Int = _        
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. The attribute annotated with `@Id` is a unique identifier of the entity and there should not be more than one of this. Please provide a specific use-case where you have the problem.

Comment: the use case is the table listed in the question. I have a table of dates, where the key is the date itself but also a surrogate key that I use to store as an external key in other tables that have dates.

Comment: But as I understand from your comment `@Id`  reflects the PRIMARY KEY defined in a table, so you cannot have two. The second one could be an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing [`@IdClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html) annotation and a declaration of a corresponding container class for your composite primary key. See [Configuring a JPA Entity Primary Key](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm) examples 7-4 and 7-5 for some details.